# Help me identify a story of chickens who defend against the foxes

Tags: story-identification, animals

I remember this story, that is sort of Sci-Fi/Fantasy, since it has talking chickens.

The chickens in this story are unique since they can fly (The talking part is apparently not worthy of notice) and they need to defend against marauding foxes.

They learn they cannot rely on the farmer and so train themselves.  They eat more grit to grow harder shells.  They sit in a hot shed, to try and boil the eggs internally, so that they can fly and dive bomb a fox with a hard boiled, hard shelled egg.

I have been driving my son crazy with Chicken references and need to track this story down to show him why it is I am so crazy.

Comment: I think this question would fit better over at [Literature](http://literature.stackexchange.com/) . The consensus I took away from a [related meta question](http://meta.scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/683/are-childrens-literature-and-cartoons-for-children-on-topic) was that children's books about talking animals don't quite belong here unless there is a strong sci-fi or fantasy element in the work.

Comment: They were Robot Chickens?

Comment: Biotech chickens?  Come on, its chickens beating up foxes, its the barn yard equivalent to Aliens vs Predators. Just more feathers and fur.

Comment: As an aside - in real life, Chickens **can** fly, just not well.  The get up in trees, and all over the place when allowed.  They are just heavy enough (with reletively small wings) they can't sustain flight for very long or straight up.  We've bred them that way over generations.

Comment: @balancedmama We are horrible people!  But they taste so yummy this way!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It sounds like The Fox Busters by Dick King Smith: http://www.puffin.co.uk/nf/Book/BookDisplay/0,,9780141316420,00.html.

Dick King Smith also wrote the book that Babe was based on.

Comment: That really looks like it, but that link claims it is published in 2004, and I clearly read this MUCH longer ago than that!  Ok, looks like a new edition, and at least as early as 1996.  Ah, it was his first book in 1978, that makes more sense.

Comment: And I bought the book for my son, but my wife won't let me read it to him yet.  Gotta wait till he is a bit older.